# CoCreateInstance returns E_NOINTERFACE in one PC

Tags: c++, com

I am using **CoCreateInstance** function to create a single object of the class associated with a specified **CLSID**. It returns E_NOINTERFACE.

I checked the registry and the **CLSID** is correct. The path of the called object dll is correct in registry and **ThreadingModel** is **Apartment**. In addition, the reference to the identifier of the interface is correct.

The newly created object context parameter is **CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER**.

While this function call is working on one PC, it is not working on another. I tried to register the dll with **regsvr32** again, but it has not solved the issue.

What could be the reason of the problem?

Comment: The 95% case is DLL Hell, having the wrong version of the component on the machine.  The remaining 5% is not having the proxy/stub DLL registered and using the apartment threaded COM object from a thread that isn't STA.  If SysInternals' Process Monitor does not tell you anything (the 5% case is a missing key in Interface registry key) then contact the author or owner for the correct install procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Most probable cause — 32/64 bit incompatibility, i.e. you’re trying to create 32 bit in-process COM object in a 64 bit application, or vice versa. Note that regsvr32 is also platform-dependent, on Win64 there’s another one in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe for registering 32-bit COM servers on a 64-bit Windows.

Another possible cause — incompatible threading models.
[Read this for explanation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041213-00/?p=37043).

**Update:** Another possible reason is that object internally might use some other COM object, and that dependent COM object isn’t registered, or is of a wrong version.
Use SysInternals Process Monitor on the failing PC to see which files/registry keys your client app tries to open immediately before CreateInstance fails with E_NOINTERFACE.
And/or use Process Explorer on the PC where it works, and see which DLLs are loaded as the result of that CreateInstance call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using Windows7 64bit, so I registered 32-bit COM server as you suggested. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem. While the CoCreateInstance returns S_OK on one machine, it returns E_NOINTERFACE on another. Both machines have the Windows7 64bit OS. I do not think it is related to threading model, because it was previously working on both machines. Do you agree? COM Server and COM Client are both 32bit.

Comment: If you are using the same client app’s binary on both machines, threading model should be the same. See the update.